# Use Chronicle Queue as Pub/Sub

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

I wanna build a micro services system, and i'm choosing the message queue.
As the title, can I use Chonicle queue as a pub/sub system? 
I read that Chronicle Queue can be used as a message passing between jvms on the same machine, but how can we achieve this on different machines?
If we use replication, on a gateway host machine we create a source queue and replicate it to sub service machine (sink), so we can pass message from gateway to sub service. How can we do the vice versa from sub service to the gateway?

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from one machine to another you can use replication. This works the same whether you pass from a gateway to a service or from a service to a gateway.

NOTE: replication is a licensed feature for Chronicle Queue.

Comment: Thank you for feedback peter,
What'll happen when I have a lot of service and some service communicate with each other? Will the number of queue also increased? And how can I manage the status of the queue e.g: some services down? Does the enterprise version offer me this feature?

Comment: @TamVu each queue is a directory with a few files, you can have a lot of them if you wish, however, I would suggest having 1 - 20 services, and 1 - 100 queues. You need only one service per machine as a minimum. If you have hundreds of machines, you might consider a different architecture.

Comment: @TamVu we detect a service being down by introducing a heartbeat message. Any tailer can then see if the service has timed out. e.g. it could be running but it has to be working to be concidered up.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting. Do you have any resource or example of using Chronicle queue for this use case? I've found in the internet but all I found is a slide about using this technique in a machine, and each cpu core is considered as a node. Thank you so much.